# 301 Redirect are these URLs equivalent?

Tags: mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

I want to redirect an entire duplicate directory to the same files in the directory above the dup_folder.

Redirect Code in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /dup_folder/ http://www.example.biz/
```

It redirects to:

```
http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm?q=dup_folder/inspection11.htm
```

But I want it to redirect to:

```
http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm
```

Is there something I can add to .htaccess to Rewrite the URL to how I want, or are the two above URLs seen as the exact same URL to a search engine?

Comment: I think this URL has the answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7539/how-to-use-htaccess-to-show-smarter-urls . I have mod_rewrite enabled. Any help with the regular expression is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else is at play here, that is causing

```
http://www.example.biz/dup_folder/inspection11.htm
```

to be converted to

```
http://www.example.biz/inspection11.htm?q=dup_folder/inspection11.htm
```

because out of the box, the use of `Redirect 301` should not add that query string.

So I'd look at the configuration of your site, the `httpd.conf` or the configuration of the relevant apache `Vhost` directive, or indeed existing `.htaccess` files, to see if you can stop whatever custom redirect process is adding the query string there.

If you can't (find or change), then the following rewrite rule in a `.htaccess` file under /dup_folder/ (assuming you remove the existing `Redirect 301` ) should remove the query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dup_folder/(.*)
RewriteRule .* /inspection11.htm? [R=301,L]
```

With the use of a trailing `?` on the rewrite, it will clear off the query string that is being added by something else.

Comment: It's been a while since I was messing with this. I'll look back into it tomorrow. The site that had this issue uses a CMS that performs it's own re-writes. Thanks for posting.